# User Generated Photos in Open Graph Story not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using a Test App with have User Generated Photos enabled on a Custom Action I'm trying to POST using the JavaScript API.

Why would this code which is consistent with the documentation return the error below ?
FB.api('me/namespace:custom_action',
  'post',
        {
          image:[{ url :"http://example.com/1.jpg", user_generated : true}],
          product: "http://example.com/view/10"
        },

Error: (#3503) "[{"url":"example.com/1.jpg","user_generated":true}]" is an invalid value for property "image:url" with type "URL"

And posting the same code, with images(plural) rather than image, executes successfully. But why would the user generated image not show in the published story ?

Answer (score 0):

When the image property names are enclosed in quotes the story posts & displays successfully

FB.api('me/namespace:custom_action',
'post',
{
'image[0][url]': "http://example.com/1.jpg",
'image[0][user_generated]': true
 product: "http://example.com/view/10"
}